# How to replace value in a dataframe based on a value in a different column

Tags: r

I'm looking for a simple solution for my problem (which I'm sure exists).

I have the following example database:

```
a    b    c    comp
10   20   30   25
15   30   40   20
```

Now, I need to find a code that will go over columns `a`, `b`, and `c`, and will replace any cell with a value larger than what is written in the comp column for that specific row.

So, in this case the result will be the following:

```
a    b    c    comp
10   20   NA   25
15   NA   NA   20
```

Any smart solutions to my problem that don't involve nest for loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should boil down to a single vectorised comparison since you are operating over `n` rows and an `n` length vector:

```
sel <- c("a","b","c")
dat[sel][dat[sel] > dat$comp] <- NA
dat
#   a  b  c comp
#1 10 20 NA   25
#2 15 NA NA   20
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table` you can try

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(x > comp, NA, x))]
```